# Use of mathematical operator at start of line

Tags: kotlin

I have a basic question for my general knowledge of Kotlin concerning the mathematical operators:

I was writing an equation and I mistakenly put the plus sign on the second line which caused my equation not to work as on the examples below:

```
val x = 2 + 3 //x = 5 CORRECT

val x = 2 +
    3 //x = 5 CORRECT

val x = 2
    + 3 //x = 2 WRONG
```

My question is: why Kotlin is not showing any error message on the last example? How is Kotlin interpreting the line "+3"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val x = 2` is correct expression, so compiler uses it as complete expression.

`+ 3` is correct expression although it doing nothing.

`val x = 2 +` is uncompleted expression - the compiler is trying to complete it using the next line.

Comment: Then to have a more specific question: why "+3" is considered a correct expression?

Comment: @Charles, there is an [unary plus operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#unary-prefix-operators) in Kotlin, and `+3` is parsed as an unary plus and  `3`.

Comment: @Charles This expression return `Int` value. Not necessary to use it. It is like function that return value. For example, you can write `object.hashCode()` and `val hashCode = object.hashCode()`, both expressions are correct.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. In my opinion the best explanation is the one of @hotkey because I was not aware that Kotlin has a unaryPlus() operator. This explains why "+3" is a correct expression.

Answer (score 3):

This is an unfortunate result of the way Kotlin assumes a semicolon at the end of lines.

In languages like Java, every statement must end with a semicolon, so there's no ambiguity.

Kotlin [allows](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#formatting) you to omit semicolons, which can be handy.  But it's a bit over-eager: it infers one at the end of every line that would make sense on its own, ignoring the following lines.  This is rather annoying to those of us who like to put operators at the start of a line, not the end…

Most of the time, the following line won't make sense on its own, so you get a compiler error to warn you of the issue.  Unfortunately, you've found one of the rare cases where the following line *is* valid, and so there's no error!  (Kotlin has a [unary plus](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#unary-prefix-operators) to match its unary minus, so `+3` is a number just like `-4`.  And a number on its own is a valid expression.  Kotlin calculates the value, and then discards it.)

The solutions are:

- Put the whole expression on the one line.  (Which is unwieldy if it's long!)
- Put the operator at the end of the previous line.  (Which is clearly what the language designers expect, but some of us find less logical and less clear.)
- Prevent the first line from making sense on its own.

The best way I've found to do that last one is with parens:

```
val x = (2
         + 3)
```

It looks awkward in a very short expression, but it works reasonably well on longer ones — not ideal, but necessary unless/until Kotlin gets smarter about where to assume semicolons…

Comment: I agree--operators at the end of lines is not nearly as clear to read as at the beginning of lines (for long expressions).  One of the many little "improvements" of kotlin, sigh.  Your solution is certainly readable, and I'll use it in my own code (while holding my nose).